# C#/js: Why div class new value doesn´t appears in c# code behind?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

my problem is:
I have a div inside a asp:updatePanel, inside in a asp:UpdatePanel.
Originally, div has a class, and this class has changed after click on other div by jquery. 
Has a button with onserverclick, but in code behind just appears the old value of the div.class.

It does not change div.class in code behind, only in js.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: my problem is: I have a div inside a asp:updatePanel, inside in a asp:Repeater. Originally, div has a class, and this class has changed after click on other div by jquery. Has a button with onserverclick, but in code behind just appears the old value of the div.class.

It does not change div.class in code behind, only in js.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you mix up front end and back end, new class will only be known in the back end if you explicitly post the value e.g. with hidden field

Comment: does your div have tag "runat=server" ?

Comment: Tks, Badiparmagi. Yes, this has a runat="server" tag.

Comment: Here the div. Eval is a string represents the style class. That class have to change when click in other div. 
<div class=<%#Eval("vClassAtivoOnOff")%> id="divAtivoOnOff" runat="server">

Comment: Tks your answer, Dimitri. So, when click in a div, I have to put some value in hiddenfield, then take them on backend. I´ll try.